# Running modelsim without the using vsim command

Tags: 14.04

I'm using an Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and I recently installed Modelsim on my system. However I can only start modelsim using the `./vsim` command in terminal.

I want to be able to run modelsim without using the terminal. Is this possible? If so, how do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a launcher file to place in `/usr/share/applications` (for all users) or in `~/.local/share/applications` (only for you). Use your favorite text editor to create the file (I'd say you call it `vsim.desktop`) and paste the following content:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=<Name of your program>
Comment=<Description of your program, can be omitted>
Exec=<path to executable>
Icon=<path to icon file or icon name in system icon cache>
Terminal=false
Categories=<categories your program belongs to, semicolon separated>
```

For ModelSim, I'd choose `Categories=Development;`. If you want to be able to open files directly with modelsim, define Exec and TryExec like this:

```
Exec=<path to executable> %U
TryExec=<path to executable>
```

After the system notices the new launcher file, it will be available in the application menu, if it doesn't contain syntax errors. Best relog for that.

Comment: it didn't work. The system hasn't recognised the application. :(

Comment: Could you add the desktop file to your question so I can have a look at it, please?

Comment: I realised the Exec statement is false!! I'm new to Ubuntu so I don't know the file extension for an executable text file!! Can you help me?

Comment: Is the file type .vco ?

Comment: Linux itself doesn't care at all about file extensions. To make a file executable, you need to set exectuable permissions using `chmod +x <filename>`, depending on ownership prepended with sudo.